# Find all triples for which $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=1$ using the pigeon hole principle.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a<b<c$. Please find all the triples for which:
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=1,$$
using the pigeon hole principle.

#### Lemma 1:

$a=2$

*Proof:* Suppose $a=1$, because $\frac{1}{n}>0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, its clear that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}>1.$, therefore $a\neq1$.

Suppose $2<a$, if we look at the reciprocal then $\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{a}$ and we can add $b,c$ into the mix like so:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}+&\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}>\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=1\\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}+&\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}>1\\
\Rightarrow &\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}>\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
From the inequalities above, $2<a$ we can say  $2<3\leq a$, which tells us $a< 4\leq b$, and $b < 5 \leq c$. We can conclude from this that $4\leq b$ and $5\leq c$ which says:
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\geq \frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} &>\frac{1}{2}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{9}{20}&>\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
Which is a contradiction. *qed*

### Conclusion

So I know the only solution to this is $(a,b,c)=(2,3,6)$, but this came from a book on the pigeon hole principle and I just cant see how. I also know I can make a brute force solution show that anything else leads to a contradiction.

With $a=2$ we can change the problem to:
$$
 \frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
Where $b<c$, show that there is one solution using the pigeon hole principle.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.  It's clearly not true that $a<b<c\implies \frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c=1$ so what are you trying to prove?

Comment: Oh, no that is an assumption in the problem. But that you I will add some more ditals to make it more clear

Comment: I edited it, is that more clear?

Comment: Yes.  I'm not sure where the pigeonhole principle comes into it.  It's clear that $a=2$ (if $a=1$ it's impossible and if $a≥3$ then the sum is $<1$).  Thus we have $\frac 1b+\frac 1c=\frac 12$.  Again it's clear that $b=3$, so we are done.  No pigeons though, so far as I can see.

Comment: It is clear that $b=3$ and $c=6$, but its not clear (crystal clear) that there are no other solutions.

Comment: Yes, it is.  Once you know that $a=2$, you have $\frac 1b+\frac 1c=\frac 12$.  If $b>3$ then $b≥4$ and $c≥5$ whence $\frac 1b+\frac 1c≤\frac 14+\frac 15<\frac 12$.

Comment: Nice thank you.

Comment: Still no pigeons in sight though.  Alas.

Comment: @lulu trichotomy has 3 states maybe those are the pigeonholes ?